# How do I run a kmeans cluster per each group in R?

Tags: r, k-means

***CLARIFICATION***
Trying to simplify my data/problem has made my question unclear, so I'm going to redo with the actual problem and data.

I have GPS data for a sports team of 18 players. 11 are playing and 7 are warming up. I would like to filter out only the 11 players that are playing - we are analyzing their performance for each minute of a game. In an ideal world I could just group_by(minute) and slice for the top 11 on certain data points... but the reality is that sometimes there are issues with the GPS units falling out, turning off, etc. So slicing would pick up the data for those not playing. I was hoping a kmeans cluster might better separate the data into two groups... but it looks like I can't just group_by(minute) and loop over each minute with a kmeans analysis.

So to illustrate the problem here is a sample data set simulating 3 minutes of data. 11 players of the 18 are playing, but in the 3rd minute Player A's gps stops working. So for the first 2 minutes I would have a "playing" group of 11, and in the 3rd minute a "playing" group of 10. distance_m and speed_zone_4m_s_m seem to be two data points that separate those who are playing from those who are not.

```
df <- structure(list(minute = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), ID = c("Player A", 
                                                                                            "Player B", "Player C", "Player D", "Player E", "Player F", "Player G", 
                                                                                            "Player H", "Player I", "Player J", "Player K", "Player L", "Player M", 
                                                                                            "Player N", "Player O", "Player P", "Player Q", "Player R", "Player A", 
                                                                                            "Player B", "Player C", "Player D", "Player E", "Player F", "Player G", 
                                                                                            "Player H", "Player I", "Player J", "Player K", "Player L", "Player M", 
                                                                                            "Player N", "Player O", "Player P", "Player Q", "Player R", "Player A", 
                                                                                            "Player B", "Player C", "Player D", "Player E", "Player F", "Player G", 
                                                                                            "Player H", "Player I", "Player J", "Player K", "Player L", "Player M", 
                                                                                            "Player N", "Player O", "Player P", "Player Q", "Player R"), 
                     distance_m = c(151.21, 4.061, 108.491, 154.341, 143.33, 4.097, 
                                    113.706, 104.542, 170.483, 154.764, 4.104, 4.552, 4.063, 
                                    2.52, 137.6, 3.564, 112.058, 100.153, 80.546, 3.043, 41.205, 
                                    97.448, 86.216, 3.048, 80.714, 114.429, 64.273, 54.399, 2.02, 
                                    6.09, 19.388, 1.592, 41.007, 3.065, 114.685, 100.096, 0, 
                                    3.536, 98.6, 150.17, 134.195, 3.024, 110.525, 108.263, 165.494, 
                                    156.567, 1.508, 6.741, 1.007, 2.525, 135.804, 1.505, 106.249, 
                                    119.402), speed_zone_4m_s_m = c(42.53, 0, 4.26, 33.9, 38.54, 
                                                                    0, 5.64, 0, 33.42, 54.96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32.26, 0, 15.1, 19.23, 
                                                                    39.51, 0, 0, 28.63, 14.53, 0, 16.06, 48.08, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                    0, 11.24, 0, 7.42, 8.81, 0, 0, 0, 19.57, 35.51, 0, 34.95, 42.99, 
                                                                    57.98, 46.33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35.26, 0, 15.38, 27.88)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                      -54L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So the final solution would analyze each minute of play and add a column to indicate whether an individual is playing or not playing.

*** Original question ***
New to trying out kmean clustering and I would like to run a kmeans cluster for each set of data and assign the result as either "high" or "low". Similar to how you can use dplyr to run a function on each group of data by using...

```
df %>% group_by(set) %>% kmeans()
```

...but in my searching it says you can't use group_by with kmeans.

Sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
high_grp <- tibble(ID = rep(1:10, time = 3, each = 1),
                   set = rep(1:3, time = 1, each = 10),
                   data = runif(30, 0.6, 1))
low_grp <- tibble(ID = rep(11:20, time = 3, each = 1),
                   set = rep(1:3, time = 1, each = 10),
                   data = runif(30, 0, 0.3))

df <- high_grp %>% add_row(low_grp)
```

I've preassigned the data to a "high" or "low" group before combining only because I don't know of a more elegant way to have the data naturally split. Basically this is what the clustering would spit back.

The kmeans would be run 3 times, once for each set, and assign each individual to  a "high" or "low" group within their set - ignoring the data from the other two.

Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: How many clusters do you want in each group?

Comment: 2 clusters to identify the high vs low groups

Comment: Still not clear. 2 groups the entire data set, `df`? Or 2 groups in `high_grp` and 2 in `low_grp`, or 2 groups in each `group` in `high_grp` (3 groups) and 2 groups in each `group` in `low_grp` (10 groups)?

Comment: Your right. This has been poorly worded. I edited to hopefully clarify.

Comment: This looks more like what you are trying to do [Detect The Changes In Timeseries Data](https://predictivehacks.com/detect-the-changes-in-timeseries-data/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First we need a vector to identify if the row came from the high or low group:

```
grp <- rep(c("high", "low"), each=30)
```

Now we run `kmeans` three times and tabulate the resulting goups:

```
kmeans1 <- kmeans(df$data, 2)
table(kmeans1$cluster, grp)
#    grp
#     high low
#   1    0  30
#   2   30   0
# 
kmeans2 <- kmeans(df$data, 2)
table(kmeans2$cluster, grp)
#    grp
#     high low
#   1   30   0
#   2    0  30
# 
kmeans3 <- kmeans(df$data, 2)
table(kmeans3$cluster, grp)
#    grp
#     high low
#   1   30   0
#   2    0  30
```

In all three runs the clusters formed match the groups you created. In the first kmeans cluster 1 is the low group and 2 is the high group. In the second and third kmeans runs cluster 1 is the high group and cluster 2 is the low group. The cluster numbers are not consistently applied from one run to another, but in this case the groups are separate enough that all three runs agree.

Comment: Sure, but `km <- replicate(3, table(kmeans(df$data, 2)$cluster, grp))` would be simpler. `km` is a 3-dimensional array so that `km[ , , 1]` is the first table and `km[ , , 3]` is the third table. `matrix(km, 3,  4, byrow=TRUE)` would collapse the results into a matrix where each run is a row.